# Android - App crashes when I delete a list item

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-delete

I made a list to display all the images I captured with their details. When I choose a list item opens a new screen with delete and edit option. When i choose to delete the item my app crashes.

In the logcat displays thiw message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference

and points this code :

```
 ImageView iv_photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cloth_image);
    iv_photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(extras.getString("photograph")));
```

In the database the delete method is :

```
public Boolean deleteCloth(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    int i = db.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    db.close();


    if (i != 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know what to do to fix it! Any help?

Comment: we need a little bit more code, and the logcat complete, so we can try to get the cause of the NPE....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the "extras" bundle is null. Investigate why is it so. Maybe your have not initialised it.

Comment: Agree. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' means that he is calling method getString() on null bundle object.